# Is SIFT invariant to color distribution,skewness and shearness?

Tags: image-processing, sift

I wanted to know whether SIFT is invariant to color distribution,skewness and shearness.I basically wanted to match the feature vectors of two images and detect whether they are similiar or not.

Answer (score 1):

"Basic" SIFT is done in grayscale, and is not, generally affine-invariant (beyond scale, rotation and translation invariance).
ASIFT is affine invariant which will be invariant to skew and shear.